# C++ Inheritance Overriding Vector Member Variable

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

Say you had an class

```cpp
class Foo
{
  // stuff
};
```

and you had a derived version of that class

```cpp
class Bar : public Foo
{
  // extra stuff
};
```

and you had a class with a vector of pointers to `Foo`s.

```cpp
class FooManager
{
public:
  std::vector<Foo*> objects;
}
```

Could you derive `FooManager` into `BarManager` where `BarManager` has a vector of pointers to `Bar`?

If you did something like

```cpp
class BarManager : public FooManager
{
  std::vector<Bar*> objects;
}
```

Then `BarManager` would just be hiding `FooManager`'s objects and I wouldn't want that extra member. I could just push `Bar` pointers into the `FooManager`'s objects and that would work, but then if I wanted to use the `extra stuff` the `Bar` object has, I would need to cast all the `Foo*`s into `Bar*`s and then there would be problems if I accidentally pushed a `Foo` pointer into objects.

Is there a better solution?

EDIT:
I am trying out different methods to organize a game’s classes. All the objects are derived from a GameObject with pure virtual Update() and Draw() methods. All objects belong to a manager of that object type, and then all those managers belong to one “Manager Manager” who will call the Update() and Draw() methods for the managers which in turn call the Update() and Draw() methods for the objects.

Comment: No, you cannot do that. C++ does not work this way. Furthermore, just because `Bar` is a subclass of `Foo` doesn't mean that `std::vector<Bar*>` is a subclass of `std::vector<Foo*>`. C++ templates don't work this way. The two vectors are completely different types that are not related to each other in any way.

Comment: So my only option is to declare ```objects``` in ```BarManager``` and hide ```FooManager```'s ```objects```?

Comment: No, `FooManager`'s vector will work just fine for storing pointers to `Bar`s. And you do not "need to cast all the Foo*s into Bar*s", because this is exactly what virtual methods are for. Virtual inheritance is one of the powerful and fundamental parts of C++ that's designed precisely for this use case. Your C++ book should have plenty of examples of how to define and implement virtual methods.

Comment: I would need to cast in the case of ```Foo``` having a member called ```a``` and ```Bar``` having a member called ```b``` (that is what I meant by extra stuff), and I want to access ```b``` from ```BarManager```. Anywho, you can turn the comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: XY problem. Why do you need that?

Comment: Sorry about that, I added some more detail to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

As one user pointed it it looks like a XY problem. You should better explain what you want to achieve.

Given only the few explanation...

One solution is to use `std::vector<Foo*> objects;` in `FooManager` and in `BarManager` to have functions that take `objects` and cast the pointers in `objects` to `Bar*`.

```
class BarManager : public FooManager {
    Bar* get_at_index(std::size_t i) const { return static_cast<Bar*>(objects[i]); }
}
```

Another approach is to use a templated class and then use either `Manager<Foo> mgr;` or `Manager<Bar> mgr;`.

```
template <class T>
class Manager
{
public:
  std::vector<T*> objects;
}
```

Comment: I believe the new concepts and constraints in C++ 20 along with the templates is what I’m looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is it not possible, it makes no sense to do so.  Imagaine what could happen if you could do this.  If something like this was allowed:

```
class BarManager : public FooManager
{
  override std::vector<Bar*> objects;  // replace the base class member with this
}
```

Then if you defined another subclass of Foo:

```
class Baz : public Foo {  // whatever
```

You could convert a `BarManagar *` into a `FooManager *`

```
FooManager *ptr = &SomeBarManager;
```

and then stick a Baz into it's data

```
ptr->objects->push_back(new Baz());
```

leading to predictable chaos when someone tried to later access it as if it was a Bar.

So the real question is *WHY* are you thinking of trying to do something like this?  Because it really doesn't make any sense, and if you think it does, there is probably something fundamentally inconsistent in your design.